# Can not find PInvoke DLL SqlCeme35.dll?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, compact-framework2.0

I am using Motorola device xr480 which does not have GUI.

When I try to access .sdf file in the device, i am getting the above error using the following code :

```
string Connection_String = @"Data Source=Application\RFID_FR_Data.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(Connection_String);
```

Please guide me to solve the issue.

Comment: How are you trying to access the file? post the code you're using please.

Comment: string Connection_String = @"Data Source=Application\RFID_FR_Data.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";  SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(Connection_String);  I am getting problem while initializing the sqlconnectionce object

Comment: please help me out  Regards,  Ahobula Reddy